# getting error in azure ip configuration

Tags: networking, azure, linux-networking, ip

I bought a centos virtual machine from Azure and installed plesk in it, I got this error when trying to define a license for my plesk,

> "This license belongs to the IP address "20.1x.10x.x1 (my public ip
> address). It cannot be activated from a different 10.0.0.0.4 (my
> private ip address) IP address!"

How can I fix this error via azure?